# Angular 2: How to get the values of dynamic dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am created the dynamic dropdown based on response data,

Console Response:

```
   Array(3)
    0:
    val_id:1
    role_id:1
    id:1
    is_optional:false
    is_text:false


    1:
    val_id:1
    role_id:1
    id: 2
    is_optional:false
    is_text:false


    2:
    val_id:1
    role_id:1
    id :3
    is_optional: false
    is_text: false
```

i am getting three dropdown from above response

```
  <div *ngIf="response != null">
       <p class="">Questions</p>
           <div *ngFor="let question of response" (ngModel)= "questions">
           <select class="dropdown" (click)="OnclickCall(questions)">
              <option> some text </option>
              <option> some text </option>
            </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

I tried with above code but not able to get the values, how should i get the value of 3rd dropdown which id is 3 onclick dropdown, so that i can pass the values and get the response for option.
Please help me.

Comment: (ngModel) in a div ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am got your question right then you can done it by below example

```
<div *ngFor="let question of response;">
   <select class="dropdown" (click)="OnclickCall(question)">
      <option *ngFor="let v of values"> Some text</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

In your component :

```
public values:any=[];
OnclickCall(question){
    // question.id that you need to use to get data
    this.values= data; //set options data that you got using question id
}
```

Comment: don't use (click) in a select

Comment: thank you, but if i select any one of dropdown option, all other dropdown option selection changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `onclick` function on the option itself and set variable to the selected option

```
<option (click)="onSelectOption(i)"> some text </option>
/// and i here is the index of the option in array
```

***Component.ts***

```
export default class Component {
    mySelectedOption;
    optionsArray;  

    onSelectOption(i) {
       this.mySelectedOption = this.optionsArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: in Angular, normally you don't use (click) in a select. you have < select [(ngModel)]="mySelect">< option value="1">one< /option>< option value="1">one< /option>< /select>